# Meteor issue with UI.renderWithData while dynamically adding Gridster widgets to DOM

Tags: meteor, gridster

I'm trying to use the gridster.add_widget method to pass pre-rendered templates into the DOM.

I must not understand how to use UI.renderWithData because I get the error message message at the very bottom each time I call the UI commands.

My understanding from the docs is that these commands will return the fully formed HTML of the template passed in.  I've validated that gridster is working right by creating a red box for each 'project' that gets called.

Any help would be mucho appreciated.  Thanks!

```
Template.projects.rendered = function(){

    gridster = $(".gridster div").gridster({
        widget_margins: [10, 10],
        widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140]
    }).data('gridster');

   var projectz = Projects.find({}, {sort: { time: -1}});
   $.each(projectz, function(index, widget){
       if (widget != undefined) {
           console.log(widget);

           // This works and adds a red box for each project in the database
           gridster.add_widget('<div style="background-color: red;">');

           // This does NOT work, I assume it is an issue with my use of UI.renderWithData
        // gridster.add_widget(UI.insert(UI.renderWithData(Template.projects, widget)), 1, 1);
       }
   });
};


//
// Error I get trying to gridster.add_widget() or console.log()
// with (UI.insert(UI.renderWithData(Template.projects, widget)));
//

Exception from Deps afterFlush function function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined
at tbodyFixNeeded (http://localhost:3000/packages/ui.js?b523ef986d3d39671bcb40319d0df8982acacfe8:1368:13)
at Function.DomRange.insert (http://localhost:3000/packages/ui.js?b523ef986d3d39671bcb40319d0df8982acacfe8:1337:7)
at Object.UI.insert (http://localhost:3000/packages/ui.js?b523ef986d3d39671bcb40319d0df8982acacfe8:2123:15)
at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/client/controllers/projects.js?c493c07746d208ff23d7a134ed4353a706244d46:41:29)
at Function.o.extend.each (http://localhost:3000/client/compatability/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js?4c694ca97ed11ffba659454ac63c35e0452a994d:2:2931)
at Object.Template.projects.rendered (http://localhost:3000/client/controllers/projects.js?c493c07746d208ff23d7a134ed4353a706244d46:37:7)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/ui.js?b523ef986d3d39671bcb40319d0df8982acacfe8:424:23
at _.extend.flush (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?7afb832ce6e6c89421fa70dc066201f16f9b9105:331:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

UI.insert expects a DOM node as a second argument, see [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#ui_insert). You are calling it without any additional arguments.

Is there a reason you aren't rendering all of the Project elements to the page in the template?